# Ternary Operator - 3 conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'd like to rewrite this with a ternary operator. I believe I need 2 operators.

```
if (a.quantity > b.quantity) {
      return -1;
  } else if (a.quantity < b.quantity) {
      return 1;
  } else {
      return 0;
  }
```

**Ternary**

```
return (a.quantity > b.quantity) ? -1 : (a.quantity < b.quantity) ? 1 : 0;
```

would this be the equivalent?

Comment: Yes ... ... ...

Comment: ...why do you want to re-write it as a conditional operator? It's less clear and doesn't save up enough space to even be worth it. You have one line instead of 5 - your minifier will do a better job than that. If you're not interested in reading all 5 lines, then most code editors come with a code folding functionality where you can collapse blocks like these. Yet the clarity from having the `if` statements and the speed of understanding and fixing the code will likely negate whatever advantage the chained conditionals have.

Comment: @VLAZ i understand what you're saying. I was just curious how to write a ternary with more than 2 options. I agree that the `if` statement is quicker to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the value for sorting, you could take the delta of the two values:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.quantity - b.quantity); // ascending
data.sort((a, b) => b.quantity - a.quantity); // descending
```

Comment: What do you mean by the delta of the two values?

Comment: it is the difference, which returns the same sign (a positive, negative or zero number) of the wanted values.

Comment: so where could that be added in place of in the ternary operator?

Comment: @mph85 you can use it when sorting, as mentioned `arr.sort((a, b) => a.quantity - b.quantity)`

Comment: @mph85 Keep in mind that `data.sort((a, b) => a.quantity - b.quantity);`, will only work for numbers (and booleans and numbers in string form).  So if you array contains normal strings and you want to sort it alphabetically then this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes those are equivalent

`return (a.quantity > b.quantity) ? -1 : (a.quantity < b.quantity) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and  the first comment supplied 5 minutes ago?

Comment: no worries man, thanks for confirming, but next time just write a comment, unless i made a mistake or something.

Comment: @nickzoum well, this being an answer. Comments aren't meant to be taken as answers and are indeed supposed to be treated as ephemeral. If that comment is gone tomorrow, then nobody would know if it's a "yes" or "no". Then again, this *has* to have been answered at some point - there is a valid argument to be had that it doesn't really need an answer.

Answer (score 0):

or maybe just

```
return (a.quantity < b.quantity) - (b.quantity < a.quantity)
```